# Cant login to Windows domain from Lock Screen when VPN is ON

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, routing, active-directory

Hello I have problem with using VPN (FortiClient) and Windows Domain Login.
Everytime when VPN is ON my local internet connection is cutted off
If I am afk and Windows Lock Screen turns on (due idle time or WIN+L),
I'm not able to login and I have to restart computer (sometimes twice time)

[image]

```
My ipconfig:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : xxx.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xxxxx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xxxx(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.6.117(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : xxxx
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : xxxx
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.6.9
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.6.14
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 241434730
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : xxxx
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.6.14
                                       10.8.6.54
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Route Table:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.8.6.9       10.8.6.117     35
         10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link        10.8.6.117    291
       10.8.6.117  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.8.6.117    291
   10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.8.6.117    291
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.8.6.117    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.8.6.117    291
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  6    291 fe80::/64                On-link
  6    291 fe80::442b:XXX:14a9:eee9/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
  6    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

IPv4 Route Table with VPN on

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.8.6.9       10.8.6.117     35
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     172.16.206.2     172.16.206.1      2
         10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link        10.8.6.117    291
       10.8.6.117  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.8.6.117    291
   10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.8.6.117    291
     91.XX.YY.18  255.255.255.255         10.8.6.9       10.8.6.117     35
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      169.XX.YY.9  255.255.255.255     172.16.206.2     172.16.206.1      1
     172.16.206.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.206.1    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.16.206.1    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.8.6.117    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.206.1    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.8.6.117    291
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
 21    331 fe80::/64                On-link
  6    291 fe80::/64                On-link
 21    331 fe80::18dc:XXX:b8c9:95fb/128
                                    On-link
  6    291 fe80::442b:XXX:14a9:eee9/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 21    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
  6    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: The behavior you describe is actually expected due to the way your VPN is configured.  What does your IT Administrator have to say about this problem?

Comment: How is your VPN configured?

Comment: @Ramhound  this is Forticlient VPN configured by/to access our customer